# Compile error: Cannot find symbol - makeFrame();

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, bluej

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Spel
{
private JFrame frame;


public Spel()
{
    makeFrame();
}
}
```

Here's my code. Im new to Java programming, and im trying to make a simple game. But i get this error when compiling, why is that?

EDIT: Solved this, thanks. Added new code:

```
private void makeFrame()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Spel");
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("titel");
    contentPane.add(label);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have any makeFrame() method either in this class, nor in any imported static classes

try to add

```
public void makeFrame() {
 System.out.println("foo");
}
```

to your Spel class and see what happens

Comment: I added some new code, it works now, i get a little small windows then creating a instance. Thank you! Code is in post. It seems like I cant write code here

Answer (score 1):

```
makeFrame();
```

Here you are calling a function named `makeFrame` From your code from above comment. Do it like

```
public class Spel
{
private JFrame frame;


public Spel()
{
    makeFrame();
}

public void makeFrame() 
{ 
 frame = new JFrame("Spel");
Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
JLabel label = new JLabel("titel");
contentPane.add(label);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: O good you have already solved it :)

Comment: Just did that, thanks !

Comment: Good :) always try on your own first :)